# Method addEagerConstraints does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm building a small application on `Laravel 5.6` where I'm having a `Company` model where I am having a `hasMany` relation to model `FinancialAndRisk` something like this:

```php
class Company extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug', 'establishment', 'parent_id', 'website', 'updates'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at','updated_at','deleted_at'
    ];

    public function financial()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Company\FinancialAndRisk', 'company_id');
    }

    public function latestFinancial()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Company\FinancialAndRisk', 'company_id')->latest()->first();
    }

}
```

Now at some places I want the latest financial report so I made a function `latestFinancial`

But when in my controller I do something like this:

```php
public function  index()
{
    $companies = Company::with('latestFinancial')->get();

    return response()->json(['companies' => $companies], 200);
}
```

I get an error:

```php
{
    "message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::addEagerConstraints does not exist.",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
    "file": "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\conxn\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php",
    "line": 2671,
```

How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your model you should define that you want an eager load with only One result, so instead of saying hasMany you should do hasOne: Also just use ->latest(); first() isn't necessary here

```
public function latestFinancial()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Company\FinancialAndRisk', 'company_id')->latest();
}
```

Then it will only give you the latest record associated

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, But I have other elements which will be coming in `with()` operator, your `static function` will not give me `latest financial` as per your code it will only fetch the `latest company`, I want `latest financial` in accordance to that `company`.

Comment: yeah it was what I understood since you used first() method I was about to write a comment to you. Editing my answer to fit your needs sec

Comment: This will do sorting with the companies latest, It will not sort with financial table

Comment: Can I use first at `$query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();` as I want only first latest value.

Comment: It might work it might not let me know please :D let's hope it does since it makes sense X)

Comment: It doesn't. I tried using `take(1)` also it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `->first()` because it executes the query. Remove it and use `HasOne`:

```php
public function latestFinancial()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Company\FinancialAndRisk', 'company_id')->latest();
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, But why it is not working in `hasMany()`?

Comment: The problem is `->first()` because it executes the query. You can also use `HasMany`, but then `$company->latestFinancial` will be a collection. I assume that's less practical.

Comment: Beucase hasMany() returns more than 1 result per company, hasOne only returns one therefore you can use latest() to get the latest one

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that i was using `->get()` at the end of the query.

I removed it and my query was fine i.e

formally i did

```
public function priceCategoryEntities()
{
    return $this->hasOne((new AppUsersVipPriceCategoriesEntity), 'price_category_id', 'id')->get();
}
```

But Now am using

```
public function priceCategoryEntities()
{
    return $this->hasOne((new AppUsersVipPriceCategoriesEntity), 'price_category_id', 'id');
}
```

and the error is gone.